# How to update this?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this :

```
   ID      ROW_A    ROW_B

'62919' | '9430' | '40754'
```

I get it thanks to this query :

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE ROW_A != 0
```

I would like to update it, to put ROW_A's  value into ROW_B

So, is it possible to make the following treatment with one query ?

Now, I'm using this (but it's wrong) :

```
UPDATE myTable SET ROW_B = ROW_A
WHERE ID IN(
SELECT * FROM myTable
WHERE ROW_A != 0)
```

Comment: Do you want ROW_A to keep its value, swap with B, or what?

Comment: just use ``WHERE ROW_A != 0`` instead of entire ``WHERE``

Comment: Do you want to swap the columns as well?

Comment: bonCodigo > no

Jeremyharris > ROW_A value becomes "0"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No need for a subquery I'd think:

```
UPDATE  myTable 
SET     ROW_B = ROW_A
WHERE   ROW_A != 0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
UPDATE myTable 
SET ROW_B = ROW_A
WHERE ROW_A != 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
UPDATE myTable SET ROW_B = A
WHERE ID IN(
SELECT ROW_A as A FROM myTable
WHERE ROW_A !=0)
```